# How to decide if a matrix is an element of a foreordained group?

Tags: matrices, group-theory

First of all, I'm a physicist. So I don't know the math as the way you guys know. I'm sorry in advance...

My question is as follows:

Let's say that I have a matrix. How can I decide which group that matrix is in? To be specific, I attempt to write one or two $3 \times 3$ matrices. I know that these matrices are complex, their determinant is 1 and their Hermitian conjugate is equal to their inverse. So are these matrices elements of $SU(3)$?

Can I say so faithfully or do I need to check some other things?

Note: a Hermitian conjugate is defined as the transpose of the complex conjugate of the matrix in physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do exactly that.

No magic is going on -- if we define a group $G$ as the set of all matrices satisfying certain properties, and you have a matrix satisfying those properties, then your matrix is an element of $G$.